# What is the best technique for shaking a can of spray paint?

Tags: spraypainting

...and why is that the best technique?
This question seeks the pros and cons of different techniques for shaking the can.  What's more effective?  What's less likely to cause injury (including injuries from repetitive movements)?

---

*This is not intended to be a subjective question or one based on style, any more than a question of "what is the best way to lift this heavy weight?" or "what is the best way to connect these wires to this outlet?"  There are some ways that are clearly better than others, and the reasons are not necessarily obvious, but someone who has a lot of experience with the subject might have figured out which ways are better than others.*

Comment: The best techniques is to convince someone else to do it...

Comment: If you are concerned about a repetitive stress injury, then you might be using the wrong medium.  That would be a lot of cans of paint per day and a lot of money out the window.  You might want to consider just moving to an air sprayer and a dedicated can shaker.

Comment: You could always [shake it like a Polaroid picture](https://youtu.be/PWgvGjAhvIw?t=235)...

Answer (score 1):

Whichever way you find easiest.  Seriously it probably doesn't make a whole lot of a difference.  Put a drop of food coloring in a bottle of water. Stir it, shake it, invert it - eventually it will mix.  All of the cans I've bought suggest shaking it for a minimum duration and that is probably meant to ensure it is mixed regardless of method.

Comment: If there's a ball bearing inside, it's there to help stir material that may have settled to the bottom of the can -- so you do want it to rattle against the bottom, and in some cases you may be able to hear a difference when the bottom is cleaner. Or not.

Comment: The "ball bearing" is actually a glass marble.  Once the paint can is empty and you let out all the pressure, you can cut open the can for a free marble!  The one's I have cut out have all been pretty attractive marbles, but your results may vary.

Comment: Wasn't sure I was remembering that correctly; thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Duct tape it to a sawzall blade :)

Comment: Hm. Some sort of framework of clamp that affixed to a recip saw is actually not a bad idea...;-)